# How do I get the file metadata from an AWS S3 file with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to simply retrieve the meta data from a file uploaded to S3. Specifically I need to the content type.

I know the file has metadata, because I can see it in S3 console. But I'm unable to get it programmatically. I must have some syntax error.

See the code below, the file.key returns the file name correctly. But the file.metadata doesn't seem to return an array with data.

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: ENV['REGION'])
file = s3.bucket(sourceS3Bucket).object(sourceS3Key)
puts file.key # this works!
puts file.metadata # this returns an empty array {}
puts file.metadata['content-type'] # empty
```

Comment: What `file.data` returns?

Comment: Great lead! file.data[:content_type] includes the file type. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aleksei Matiushkin suggested `file.data[:content_type]` will give the file type.